# C# Print Word Document without opening Word or Printerselection

Tags: c#, printing, ms-word, interop

I tried using the code below, using `PrintDocument`, etc.. but can't get it to work.

Every time I run the Code below it opens a window asking me to select a printer. Using `PrintDocument` always led to empty pages, but the docs got printed.

How can I print Word documents without opening any windows?

```
foreach (string doc in dirFiles) 
{
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();

    info.Verb = "print";
    info.FileName = doc;
    info.Arguments = SelectedDrucker; //Printername
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;

    Process.Start(info);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the Word application can correctly print a Word document as it interprets the content/layout as it's sent to the printer. You first need to open the document in the Word application, then use its `PrintOut` method.

(This is also what Windows does when a user right-clicks a Word file and selects "Print".)

So there's no way to print a document without opening a window. You can, however, minimize the Word document window once it's been opened.

Comment: Thanks, opening the document, setting the ActivePrinter for Word and not making the Doc visible did the trick!